# Passing parameters from CMD file to SQL script

Tags: sql-server, command-line-interface, sqlplus

I am somewhat new at this and I am having trouble.  I am calling a CMD file that then calls a SQL script to execute some database commands.

The relevant CMD file code is:
set days = '360' 
sqlplus  @\file.sql %days%

The SQL script excerpt is:
define numOfDays = &1
EXEC (numOfDays, .....)

When executed, I get an error saying the numOfDays  variable is undeclared. FYI, this is a Windows OS with a Oracle database. Any help would be appreciated and more info can be provided if needed.  Thanks.

EDIT:
Added the '%' signs around the 'days' parameter that were accidentally left out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by surrounding the param with %.

e.g:

```
SET days=360
sqlplus @\file.sql %days%
```

This is how bat/cmd files recognize the variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I actually did have that in the CMD file already.  My apologies for omitting that info.